# Irrational inequalities question: $\sqrt { -3x+1 } + \sqrt {6x+1} < \sqrt {3x+4}$ and $\sqrt { -6x+10 } + \sqrt {-x+2} \gt \sqrt {4x+5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic, radicals

Consider the following inequalities: 
\begin{equation*}
 \sqrt { -3x+1 } + \sqrt {6x+1} \lt \sqrt  {3x+4}, \\
 \sqrt { -6x+10 } + \sqrt {-x+2} \gt \sqrt {4x+5}.
\end{equation*}

Attempt at a solution; after performing all the standard actions, I got: $\frac 16\lt x \le\frac 13 $  or  $\frac {-1}{6}\le x \lt 0 $, for first inequality, and:  $\frac {-34}{97}\lt x \lt 1 $  for the second.

Official results state however:  $\frac {-1}{6}\le x \lt 0 $  for first inequality, and
 $\frac {-5}{4}\le x \lt 1 $ for the second.

What was my mistake?

Comment: If you could show how you got your solution, people might be able to tell what your mistake was.

Comment: For us to be able to tell your mistakes, we must see your "standard actions" written in detail.

Comment: Your solution for the first inequality looks good.  For e.g. it is easy to check $x = \frac{1}{3}$ satisfies, but is not covered in what you say are "official results".

Comment: Your solution for the first inequality is correct, and the official results for the second is correct.

Comment: Are you sure? I double checked both of them and they still yield the same results..

Comment: Your solution for the first inequality seems correct to me. I checked it a got the same result as you.

Comment: Has anyone tried the second inequality?

Comment: For the second, you got a $2\sqrt{(2-x)(10-6x)} > 11x-7$ or so on the way, and then squared it? Note that this inequality is fulfilled if $x < \frac{7}{11}$ no matter what the left hand side is (as long as that is valid), and squaring imposes a spurious restriction on the absolute values.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You can easily check that $x=-1$ satisfies the second inequality. So your solution is clearly wrong. "What was my mistake?" How can we possibly know that?

Comment: @TonyK no wonder you gain enemies here all the time.....you seem to be seeking an argument in every comment you make

Comment: No, you are quite wrong $-$ most of my comments are well meant and well received. In this case, I gave you a nice counterexample, and expressed what everybody else was thinking: how can we find your mistake if you don't show us your work? My feeling here is that you owe me an apology.

Answer (score 1):

I premise you find this matter in every precalculus textbook.

About the second inequality:

The point is that the set of the solutions of $$\sqrt A>B$$ is given by the **union** of the sets of the solutions of the two systems $$\begin {cases} A \ge 0 \\ \\ B<0 \end {cases}\quad ,\quad \begin {cases} B \ge 0 \\ \\  A>B^2 \end {cases}$$

Use this after the first squaring.

Of course at the start you must find the set of the *admissible* solutions, solving $$\begin {cases} -6x+10 \ge 0 \\ \\ -x+2 \ge 0 \\ \\  4x+5 \ge 0 \end {cases}$$

There is no problem with the first squaring because the two sides, where they exist, are not negative.

About the first inequality: $$\sqrt A<B \quad \rightarrow \quad \begin {cases} A \ge 0 \\ \\ B>0 \\ \\ A<B^2\end {cases}$$

**addendum** (for the second inequality):

The set of the admissible solutions is $$\left[-\frac 5{4},\frac 5{3}\right]$$
The sets of the solutions of the two systems are $$\left]-\infty,\frac 7{11}\right[ \quad,\quad \left[-\frac 7{11},1\right[$$
Therefore their *union* is $$\left]-\infty,1\right[$$
The *intersection* of the latter and the set of the admissible solutions is the solution set.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: The official solution states otherwise ; $\frac {-5}{4}\le x \lt 1 $

Comment: In effect $$\left[-\frac 5{4},\frac 5{3}\right] \cap \left ]-\infty,1\right[ = \left [-\frac 5{4},1 \right[$$ really ! Check on the real line ...

Answer (score 0):

The second equation became $ 97x^2-66x-31<0$

$(97x+31)(x-1)<0$

Therefore

$$-\frac{31}{97}<x<1$$

This condition satisfies all conditions.